# Heston model computations

Tags: options, option-pricing, heston

In the Heston model the dynamics of a single-asset $S$ are given by:

$dS_t = rS_tdt+S_t \sqrt{V_t}dW^S$

where $W^s$ is a brownian-motion $W^S$ and the square root variance process $V$ is given by the SDE:

$dV_t = a(\bar{V}- V_t)dt + \eta \sqrt{V_t}dW_t^V$,

with $a,\bar{V}, \eta$ constants and $W^V$ has fixed correlation to $W^S$ equal to $\rho$.

I want to compute the conditional expectation, $E[ V_t | S_t ] $. By solving the SDE for the Variance-process the problem reduces to computing a stochastic integral,

$E [ \int_{0}^{t}...dW_s^V | S_t]$. Anyone has any idea how to compute that?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know there is no closed-form solution to the SDE. The square-root variance process is a [Cox-Ingersoll-Ross (CIR) process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox%E2%80%93Ingersoll%E2%80%93Ross_model) thus its distribution is **non-central Chi-squared**. The process can be characterized as [a sum of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/31863/cir-process-from-ornstein-uhlenbeck-process).

Comment: As Heston has analytic characteristic function I calculated this same conditional expectation using Fourier-based methods ala Oosterlee & Ruijter.

Comment: @ James Spencer-Lavan - Do you have any paper in mind that I should look at? I found a ton of bibliography out there but many of the papers are irrelevant. Thank you

Comment: This is an ok reference on 2d COS inc Heston bivariate characteristic function https://open.uct.ac.za/bitstream/handle/11427/8520/thesis_sci_2014_com_moir_r.pdf;sequence=1

Answer (score 2):

A quick trick:

from "Dupire, A Unified Theory of Volatility" we have 
$$E[V_t | S_t] = \sigma_{\text{loc}}(S_t, t)^2$$ 
where $\sigma_{\text{loc}}(S, t)$ is the local volatility. We also have from the Dupire formula that 
$$
\sigma_{\text{loc}}(K, T)^2 = \frac{\frac{\partial C}{\partial T}}{\frac{1}{2}K^2\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial K^2}}
$$
(in the case where drift and interest rate are zero, otherwise there are additional terms),
and finally there are semi-analytic formulas for the call price $C(K,T)$, based on Fourier transform as mentionned by @ James Spencer-Lavan, for which you will find plenty of implementations. So you have all the ingredients readily available for your calculation.

Comment: I see your point and I fully agree with that. In particular I have something more general to compute, namely $E[V_t^1 | S_t^1, S_t^2 ]$, where the brownian of the variance of asset 1 is also correlated to the brownian of asset 2.